# Upgrade from TFS 2017 to Azure DevOps - build/release pipeline

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

My company is considering upgrading our on prem TFS 2017 update 3 to the latest Azure DevOps Server (notably, the on prem variety).

During discussions about that possibility, one key stakeholder claimed that if you upgrade, all of your build and release pipelines would have to be rebuilt from scratch.  We have a healthy number of build and release definitions in TFS 2017.

I have looked for the answer in the Microsoft documentation about what exactly gets upgraded, but unfortunately I can't get the level of granularity which would prove or disprove the above claim.  On the surface it would seem like a horrible upgrade story if it were true.  But I also understand that designs and architectures change and upgrades aren't always possible.

Could somebody let me know whether the build and release pipelines can survive the upgrade more or less unscathed?  Knowing this would be a valuable data point as we work toward a decision.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using XAML build definitions?

Comment: We are not using XAML build definitions.  Thanks!

Comment: Hello Vito, this isn't blocking me.  I've marked what I consider to be the answer.  Again, the Microsoft documentation isn't granular enough to say anything specifically about Build or Release pipelines, but @Matt has answered that part of the upgrade specifically.  With that information in hand, we can make a decision without the fear of losing the hard work we have put into defining all the build and release pipelines.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vNext build definitions and the release pipeline I would expect would be pretty lift and shift.  Depending on the tasks that you have defined, they might no longer be supported or there might be new versions.  The UI will let you know that new versions are available.

A lot of the new focus is building out the features for the YAML build definitions.  If you want to leverage those, you'd have to do a lot more rework of converting those vNext tasks into YAML.  But converting is not really a hard requirement.

You mentioned that you aren't using the XAML build definitions, but if you happened to be using them, I would image that is where a lot of the rework comes in.  Having done that in the past, I can say it is a pain if you have to do it.

Comment: Thank you!  I double checked and it turns out that we do have some XAML build definitions.  After we upgraded to 2017 we slowly transitioned our builds over to the vNext format... but not all the builds have completed that journey.  So we'll need to take care of those before we upgrade, should we decide to move forward.  Thanks again for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

> all of your build and release pipelines would have to be rebuilt from scratch.

I've tested it and it won't lose any data after upgrading. We should use scheduled backups to ensure that we always have backups in place in case something goes wrong.

we can use that new hardware to do a dry run first, and then we will wipe everything clean and use it again for the production upgrade.

For our dry run, the steps for our upgrade will be:

1. Copy recent database backups to our new SQL instance.
2. Install TFS 2015 on our new application tier.
3. Use scheduled backups to restore the database backups.
4. Run through the upgrade wizard, being sure to use a service account which does not have any permissions in our production environment. See Protecting production in the dry run in pre-production document for more information.
5. Optionally configure new features which require changes to our existing projects.

The production upgrade steps will be quite similar. There the steps will be:

1. Take the production server offline using [TFSServiceControl's quiesce command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/command-line/tfsservicecontrol-cmd?view=tfs-2015). The goal here is to ensure that the backups we use to move to our new hardware are complete and **we don't lose any user data.**
2. Take new backups of each database.
3. Copy the backups to our new SQL instance.
4. Install TFS 2015 on our new application tier.
5. Use the scheduled backups wizard to restore the database backups.
6. Run through the upgrade wizard, using our desired production service account.
7. Optionally configure new features which require changes to our existing projects.

You can refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/walkthrough?view=tfs-2015) for more details.